# What does an 'F' in the Format specifier of printf mean?

Tags: c, printf, format-string, format-specifiers

What does `%.8Ff` format specifier in printf do?
What does `F` mean?

Comment: Why do you have both 'F' _and_ 'f'? You use either one or the other. Could you provide a bit more context?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [manual](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html):

> The F conversion specifier produces
>   "INF", "INFINITY", or "NAN" instead of
>   "inf", "infinity", or "nan",
>   respectively.

In your format string `%.8Ff`, the `f` is treated as a literal character and printed as an `f`.

Comment: But you're not supposed to use both like that.  It will result in the `F` not being part of the conversion specification.  This is probably undesired, unless you want output like INFf or NANf. :)

Comment: @Matthew: Right,his `f` is a literal `f` no a part of format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

One possible use of putting a literal `f` after the format specifier could be to print a string that's later to be parsed by a C or C++ compiler as a `float` constant instead of `double` constant.